# Parse nanoseconds with polars

Tags: python-polars

Is it possible to parse dates with nanoseconds in polars?

```py
>>> pl.Series(['2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456789']).str.strptime(pl.Datetime)
shape: (1,)

datetime[μs]

2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456
```

Notice how the nanoseconds were stripped off

---

Equivalent in pandas:

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456789'])
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456789'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have expected specifying `ns` as the time_unit to work:

```
>>> pl.Series(['2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456789']).str.strptime(pl.Datetime(time_unit="ns"))
shape: (1,)
Series: '' [datetime[ns]]
[
    2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456
]
```

Perhaps this is a "bug"?

---

**[UPDATE]:** This was fixed in [polars 0.15.15](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/commit/6a1d8bf7f2d3f6fb7c781f0be03eacc6dec57a48)

```
>>> pl.Series(['2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456789']).str.strptime(pl.Datetime("ns"))
shape: (1,)
Series: '' [datetime[ns]]
[
    2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456789
]
```

---

Explicitly passing a format seems to work:

```
>>> pl.Series(['2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456789']).str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%.f")
shape: (1,)
Series: '' [datetime[ns]]
[
    2020-01-01 00:00:00.123456789
]
```

Comment: I think the bug happens [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/10f2d6184662ab1ccf9f38bb159f126a2b6d0487/polars/polars-time/src/chunkedarray/utf8/infer.rs#L41)? If no fmt is passed, it calls into infer.rs.  While it's parsed, it's being casted to a DateTime with units of microseconds, no matter the time_unit passed. (The actual cast is on line 138.)

Comment: @NickODell Thank you very much for the explanation. Looks like someone posted a fix on the issue tracker: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6228